# Cumulative Sum with >=0 Restriction in Matlab

Tags: matlab, cumulative-sum

I want to calculate the cumulative sum of a vector, but stop summing up once the sum becomes negative, and start again at positive elements.

Example:

We have a vector:

```
[1 1 -1 -1 -1 -1 1 1 1 1]
```

The normal cumulative sum would then be:

```
[1 2 1 0 -1 -2 -1 0 1 2]
```

But i want:

```
[1 2 1 0 0 0 1 2 3 4]
```

The only solution i could come up with was to loop over the elements of the vector like this:

```
test = [1 1 -1 -1 -1 -1 1 1 1 1];
testCumsum = zeros(size(test));

for i=1:length(test)
    if i==1
        testCumsum(i) = test(i);
    else
        testCumsum(i) = testCumsum(i-1) + test(i);
    end

    if testCumsum(i)<0
        testCumsum(i) = 0;
    end
end
```

Is the a more matlab-ish solution?

(The sum can become negative an arbitrary number of times, the vectors can become pretty large, and the elements can be any number, not just 1 and -1)

Comment: It seems difficult because the calculation of the next element in the array depends on the calculation on the previous element plus a condition.

Comment: I suggest you add the loop solution to your question for absolute clarity (it also may well be the correct solution)

Comment: Don't use `cumsum` as a variable name!!! You'll hide the Matlab function!

Comment: I often wish that Matlab had a `cumfun(@f, ...)` function generalizing `cumsum`. It would be really useful

Comment: @Dan whoops, wasn't careful when doing this example.

Comment: @LuisMendo yes, that would be nice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to vectorize it since you have to decide on each elemenet based on previous ones. You can find regions of positive and negative runs but it would be unnecessarily complex and I don't know if you can gain over your own solution.

Here is a simplification of your code for input `A` and output `C`:

```
C=A;
C(1) = max(C(1), 0);
for k=2:numel(C)
    C(k) = max(C(k-1)+C(k), 0);
end
```

Answer (score -1):

```
call your vector x, 
y=x >0 
z=x.*y
sum(z)
```

the y vector is 0 / 1 where the elemnts of x are greater than 0 the dot product to get z sets your negative values to 0, and then you can sum

_Ah i see more clearly what you want to do now, - looping is probably going to be quickest, you could break into block segments if the array is large and use parfor to speed it up

Comment: problem is, i still need to use negative values that cause the sum to decrease, but not go below zero. Your method gives me [1 2 2 2 2 2 3 4 5 6]